# Should a sentence with "both start and end dates" be plural?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Which is correct:

Enter both the start and end date for implementation.

Enter both the start and end dates for implementation.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, 'date' should remain singular.

This is because there is only one start date, and one end date. You are referring to them individually, not as a group, so neither is plural

If you said "start and end *dates*" it could mean there are more than one of each.

However, you could group the 'start date' and 'end date' together and say "*enter the dates*" if you thought there was no need to specify what the two individual dates were.

If you think about the example "*men and women*". These are two nouns, both plural. You understand that this must mean there are several of each. If there was only one of each, you'd say "a man and a woman". But, if you didn't need to differentiate between the man and the woman, you could group the two together and use a plural word like "people".